# Angular error => http://localhost/angulav/public/auth 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I am trying to do a login POST request with angular but i keep getting this error `http://localhost/angulav/public/auth 500 (Internal Server Error)`. I want to post a login form using angular with laravel and know how angular can be able to use the laravel URL from the route. If i do it with laravel, it gives me an exception error.

This is my route.php

```
 Route::any('/', function() {
 return view('layout.master');
 })->where('path', '.+');

 Route::post('auth', 'UserController@Login');
 Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

This is my userController.php

```
 public function login(request $request)
  {
    $user_data = [
      'username' => $request->input('username'),
      'password' => $request->password('password')
    ];

    if (Auth::attemp($user_data)) {
       return response(Auth::user(), 201);
    } else {
      return response('username and password do not match', 403);
    }
}
```

This is my script

```
 angular.module('myApp').controller('mainController', 
 ['$scope', '$http',          function($scope, $http){
   angular.extend($scope, {
   doLogin: function(loginForm) {
   $http({
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    url: baseUrl + '/auth',
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      username: $scope.login.username,
      password: $scope.login.password
    }
  }).success(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    });
     }
   });
 }]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `Login` in the route, but using `login` in the controller. However, `L!=l`.

```
Route::post('auth', 'UserController@Login');

public function login(Request $request)
```

You also need write `Request $request` instead of `request $request`. Please check similar errors.

Comment: You also need write `Request $request` instead of `request $request`. Please check similar errors.

Comment: I have made the correction but still. i think it cannot find the url call `/auth`